# Bootstrapping buttons

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to make  three parallel square shape buttons with title in center. something like this

```
                                      My title

Square button-1                    square button-2             square button-3
```

My code is as follows::

```
<div class="col-md-12 pt-md-5 text-center">
  <p>My title</p>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
     <div>
        <button class="btn btn-sq-lg btn-info">button-1</button>
     </div>
     <div >
      <button class="btn btn-sq-lg btn-info">button-2</button>
     </div>
     <div>
      <button class="btn btn-sq-lg btn-info">button3</button>
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>

.btn-sq-lg {
    width: 150px !important;
    height: 150px !important;
  }
```

output I am getting is three vertical without any spaces. But I want three parallel square buttons with equal spaces

how can I do that?
Also how can I make button with white color and black text and title with white color and increase font size?

Just made button as info but want  a white background with black text

Comment: You do not have a title, you have a paragraph. If you want to have a title then you would need something like `<h1> My title </h1>`

Comment: what about buttons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`col-xs-**` has been replaced with `col-**` in v4. You need to separate each `button`  with `col-4`

```css
.btn-sq-lg {
  width: 150px !important;
  height: 150px !important;
  background: #ffff!important;
  color: black!important
}

.square {
  text-align: center
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<p class="p-5 w-100 text-center">My title</p>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="square">
        <button class="btn btn-sq-lg btn-info ">button-1</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="square">
        <button class="btn btn-sq-lg btn-info">button-2</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="square">
        <button class="btn btn-sq-lg btn-info">button3</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How I can have white background and black color text inside buttons instead of info button

Comment: how to give some gap between titlee and buttons and put middle button just below title?

Comment: can you please help a bit more?

Comment: title not  coming just above middle button. It is starting from  right side of middle suare button

Answer (score 0):

Use [`justify-content-between`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/) to `row` and remove the div with `col-xs-4` (`xs` does not exist in bootstrap 4)

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12 pt-md-5 text-center">
  <p>My title</p>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-between">
    <div>
      <button class="btn btn-sq-lg btn-info">button-1</button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button class="btn btn-sq-lg btn-info">button-2</button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button class="btn btn-sq-lg btn-info">button3</button>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: tell me for more help